# verify email opened

Tags: php, email

once we send email from php using mail() function, is there any way to check either mail is open or not?

may be any type of database insertion code in email..?

or calling any function from website?

any possibility.........

i search on internet all the day but did't found any ans.

Thanks

Comment: There is no 100% precise way to do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Small images - called Web Bugs - are the only direct way as Szere Dyeri points out, but they are increasingly frowned upon and blocked by every major mail client for privacy reasons now. I would not consider them a reliable way to tell whether an E-Mail has been read any more.

There is a **legitimate way** to request a read receipt by adding the following header to the E-Mail:

```
Disposition-Notification-To: your@address.com
```

Sending of this notification can be turned off by the recipient of course.

Answer (score 6):

Add an invisible small sized image to the email content. And, let the image point to a unique url on your website. You will know that email is opened once that url is accessed. But this will not work in email clients that does not show images in the emails by default.

I found this web service called [Get Notify](http://www.getnotify.com/). They claim they do this for free but you need to verify for yourself.

Comment: Almost all e-mail clients, including webmail clients, block external images by default since several years ago, to a large part exactly to prevent using this technique of determining if a mail has been opened.

Comment: Please dont do this for public facing services. This is almost 100% considered "questionable" activity in email. Many applications will block this behaviour directly, and many scanning applications will look for images that cannot be seen by the user (0,0 size, 100% transparent, etc)

Comment: I agree with GrayWizard, it's better to include a real image in the email, like a logo, and send the unique ID inside the url like <img src="http://blah.com/logo.php?id=1234"> and that url spits out the mime header & binary data for an actual image, not a HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this would be to include an image in the email that resided on your server which includes a key to match to the user you are sending the email to.  For example, I send an email to Joe@mail.com.  In my database (or other storage system) I have Joe@mail.com matched to key 0100.  In his email I include an image, like

```
<img src="http://www.myserver.com/image/?key=0100" />
```

On your server, /image/ needs to return an image, even a 1 pixel .png.  Now you have the key that the user was assigned and can act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Many people responded that adding a "tracking image" is a "frowned upon" method and 'considered "questionable" activity'.

Out of curiosity lets say we didn't include a separate tracking image but rather we included this method in an existing image like for instance added it onto your companies logo image like:

http://mycompany.com/images/logo.png?track=2742'>

At least with this method your tracking image won't get blocked by any scanning applications.

Answer (score 0):

One legitimate way to do this is to only send textual information in the email asking the user to follow a link which you can then track. Something along the lines of:

```
//lots of good info to identify yourself/company
Thank you for your request...

Please follow this link: http://somewhere/ for tracking information
```

Unfortunately this leaves it in the users hands to acknowledge your request. This is considered to be the most respectful way to do it.

If your application is not public facing (i.e. an internal app for your company), then the img src method already posted is a good technique.